# Active object falls only through parts of the other active object

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

i have these red cylinders that should slide into these[image] slots. It works great in the middle of the object with the slots. But at both ends the red cylinders keep falling through the slots and land on the surface of the object underneath. I added some pics.
Maybe someone can help me out. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: did you add that object as a rigid body?

Comment: Yes. Both the cylinders and the object with the slots are active rigid bodies.

Comment: well then what is the length/size of that cylinder?(from the measure tool)

Comment: D=0.7m L=2m, But on the first pic you can see it fits inside the slot and doesnt fall through. But it falls through the slots at both ends.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have edited the object after applying the RB, delete the the current RB sim and reapply with collision type as mesh.

edit:i think I know the problem your object does not move, normally rbs are added to moving objects by default, yours doesn't, causing some problems, i tried recreating the scene and ended up with messing in the sensitivity panel and the dynamics parts, what you want to do is try adding a small amount of sensitivity, and disable the dynamics in it, reply if this worked.

Comment: makes sense. But i dont know how to to that.

Comment: It also doesnt fall through when the object with the slots is set as passive. With passive everything works as it should. But as active object it falls through but only at the ends.

Comment: just do what you did before and change the collision type from convex(weird sphere icon) to mesh(monkey)

Comment: I tried it. Didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer that worked for me in older thread. 
Object > Apply > Scale

Worked. Thanks anyway